# Trigger sometimes not firing on Update and Inserted

Tags: sql, triggers

I have two tables

First table Listexecutionaction which consists of no. of Actions. Structrue of table as follows

```
QueueId  ActionId  Executed
135      44         1
135      45         1
135      46         1
135      47         1
135      48         1
```

Second table Listqueue which consists of summary of total actions done. Structure as follows

```
DDBMSKEY    NoOfActivities   Completed
135         5                3
```

My requirement is for every Insert and Update on Listexecutionaction table it  should calculate NoOfActivities and No. of Actions completed. For this I wrote trigger on table on Listexecutionaction as follows.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Common].[ActivityStatus_AfterInsertUpdate] ON  [Common].[ListExecutionAction] AFTER Insert,Update
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE COMMON.LISTQUEUE   
    SET 
        NOOFACTIVITIES=
                    (SELECT count(ID) FROM common.listexecutionaction WHERE queueid=lstact.queueid),
        Completed=
                    (SELECT count(ID) FROM common.listexecutionaction WHERE queueid=lstact.queueid And Executed=1)
    FROM common.listqueue lstqueue left join common.listexecutionaction lstact 
    ON lstqueue.DDBMSKey= lstact.queueid 
    WHERE lstqueue.DDBMSKey in (Select queueid from Inserted)

END
```

My desired output for table Listqueue should be as follows

```
DDBMSKEY  NoOfActivities  Completed
135       5               5
```

But sometimes trigger is calculating wrong result in no. of actions completed and giving result as

```
DDBMSKEY  NoOfActivities  Completed
135       5               3
```

Please suggest what is wrong in the trigger. Sometimes it works fine and fails sometime.
I want to trigger on both Insert and Update

Comment: Did you check whether `Executed=1` for all 5 records in question?

Comment: Yes it is not specific to 5 records it's based on condition which is correct.

Comment: so all records have Executed=1 ?

Comment: Yes all records have Executed 1

Comment: So what is the issue ultimately, trigger "not firing" or trigger "calculating wrong result"?

Comment: Trigger is firing but sometimes give wrong result as i mentioned with example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your query can be simplified to this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Common].[ActivityStatus_AfterInsertUpdate] 
    ON  [Common].[ListExecutionAction] AFTER Insert,Update
    AS 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE COMMON.LISTQUEUE   
        SET 
            NOOFACTIVITIES=
                        (SELECT count(ID) 
                         FROM common.listexecutionaction 
                         WHERE queueid=lstact.queueid),
            Completed=
                        (SELECT count(ID) 
                         FROM common.listexecutionaction 
                         WHERE queueid=lstact.queueid And Executed=1)
        WHERE lstqueue.DDBMSKey in (Select queueid from Inserted)

    END
```

I don't think that will solve the problem, at least query is shorter.